# Flask-Login using pytest

Tags: flask, pytest, flask-login

I am trying to make a test suite that logs into to my flask app, but it always returns an anonymous user.  Here is my code:

conftest.py:

```
import pytest
from wahoo_connect import init_app, db
from wahoo_connect.models import User

from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('.flaskenv')

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def app():
    app = init_app()
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
        user = User(username='testuser', email='test@gmail.com', forename='Test', surname='User', confirmed=True)
        user.set_password('testing')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        yield app

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

The test:

```
def test_index_page__logged_in(client):
    with client:
        client.post('/auth/login', data=dict(username='testuser', password='testing'), follow_redirects=True)
        assert current_user.username == 'testuser'
```

and my login route:

```
@auth_bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    # Login route logic goes here
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('home_bp.index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password', 'warning')
            return redirect(url_for('auth_bp.login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('home_bp.index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('auth/login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

The test suite is harder to write than the code!

Comment: Have you set a "user loader" callback in your application? If not be sure to have it properly configured according to the flask-login documentation: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#how-it-works

Comment: I will look into that. The authentication works fine in my development server though.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the root of your problem is that you need to push a request context: Replace `with client:` with `with client.application.test_request_context():` or simply `app.test_request_context():`.

But writing a `POST` request to the login route every time authentication is necessary is cumbersome when most of your routes require a logged-in user. To make our lives easier, we can implement a Flask-Login version of the approach suggested in the [official Flask tests tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/tutorial/tests/). Note that I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy, but this should work without it.

In my setup, the `app` fixture does not handle database setup and teardown; instead, the `client` fixture implements `db.create_all` and `db.drop_all` to ensure fresh `db` instances for each test. In this setup, it would be undesirable to include a test user in the database every time the `client` fixture is invoked.

The basic approach is as stated in the tutorial: First write an `AuthActions` class that implements a `login` and `logout` method. We write use an `auth` fixture that requests the `client` fixture and returns an instance of `AuthActions`. Test functions can request the `auth` fixture and call the `login` or `logout` method as needed during the test.

Here's the `AuthActions` class and the `auth` fixture, which depends upon an elsewhere-defined `Users` model.

```py
#conftest.py

import pytest
from app import init_app, db
from app.models import Users

class AuthActions():
    def __init__(self, client, username='TestUser', password='TestPass'):
        self.client = client
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def create(self):
        with self.client.application.app_context():
            test_user = Users(username=self.username, password=self.password)
            test_user.save()

    def login(self):
        return self.client.post(
            '/login',
            data={'username': self.username, 'password': self.password}
        )

    def logout(self):
        return self.client.get('/logout')

# Define client and other fixtures here ...

@pytest.fixture
def auth(client):
    return AuthActions(client)
```

Now let's test a route that requires authentication. Keep in mind that you'll need to push a request context to make the authentication work:

```
#test_routes.py

def test_secret_route_unauthenticated(client):
    # passes
    with client.application.test_request_context():
        response = client.get('/secret')
        assert response.status_code == 403
        assert not current_user.is_authenticated

def test_secret_route_authenticated(client, auth):
    # passes
    with client.application.test_request_context():
        auth.create_user()
        auth.login()
        response = client.get('/secret')
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert current_user.is_authenticated

def test_secret_route_authenticated(client, auth):
    # fails; no request context
    auth.create_user()
    auth.login()
    response = client.get('/secret')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert current_user.is_authenticated
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to login

```
def login(client):
    """Login helper function"""
    return client.post(
        "auth/login",
        data=dict(username='testuser', password='testing'), 
        follow_redirects=True
    )
```